# How does string::npos know which string I am referring to?

Tags: c++, string

I am working through a book on C++ and it just covered using `string::npos` to check if a character position exists in a string.  I don't understand how this mechanism could possibly know which string I'm referring to, though!  This specific code is counting the number of occurrences of a substring.

**Code:**

```
for (int i=cats.find("cat",0);i!=string::npos;i=cats.find("cat",i)) {
    ++catCount;
    ++i;
}
```

I understand that it is starting the loop at the first occurrence of the word, incrementing the counter every pass through to avoid counting the same substring twice, and then at the end of each loop the counter is jumping to the position of the next occurrence of the substring.  The loop stops when the counter does not exist as a character index for the string.

The string is called cats though, and "cats" is nowhere to be found in "string::npos" so how in the heck does it know that's the variable I'm even searching?  Is it simply because that was the last variable to call `.find()`?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a constant that `find` returns if it can't find what it's looking for.

Comment: `find()` returns the value `npos` stored as a static data member of `std::string` if it cannot find the string.

Comment: And I assume "static data member" means the same thing here as it does in other OO languages, which is that the same value will be returned if it is accessed from anywhere in the program and that no instance of the object needs to be present for the value to be accessed and manipulated?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 9):

If `find` cannot find what you are looking for, it returns a sentinel value, `std::string::npos`.  There is no need to know anything about the string itself.  All that is needed is to return a value which cannot be a valid index.

For example, it could be implemented as:

```
static const size_t npos = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

size_t string::find(...)
{
    // if we didn't find it...
    return npos;
}
```

Also, you should not be using an `int` to store the return value as it is not what `find` returns. What if you have a very long string and the index returned is > `numeric_limits<int>.max()`?  Well now you have invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: So then I have to check for string::npos before calling find() on a different string since this is a static property, correct?

Comment: @JS In order to determine if `find()` returned a valid index, you should check the return value to see if it did not return the value `std::string::pos`. There's no mandatory action that must be taken because of `npos`'s `static` nature. `find()` simply returns a special value when it can't find the string, and to know if it returned a valid index, you need to check if the return value is *not* that special value.

Comment: @JS: No.  As @0x499602D2 said, it is simply a sentinel value, i.e., a value returns from `find` that you can use to determine if the string you were looking for was found.  The fact that it is static is irrelevant.  If `find` can't find what you're looking for, it returns `npos`, so now you know that it did not.  If it returned something other than `npos` you know that it is a valid index into your string.

Answer (score 5):

`find` returns a `std::string::size_type`.  `std::string::npos` is a constant of that type which is returned when the value cannot be found.

Note that `std::string::size_type` is an *`unsigned`* value, and `int` is signed.  If `std::string::npos` cannot be represented as an `int`, then the conversion from `std::string::npos` to `int` is undefined behavior.

So you really shouldn't store the return value of `std::string::find` in an `int`.  Instead, you should store it in a `std::string::size_type`, or in C++11 use `auto`.  `baisc_string<char>` `size_type` is `std::size_t`, as is most other specializations.

Comment: @douglaso.moen `basic_string` has an unspecified `size_type`:  you are saying `std::basic_string<char>` has a `size_type` specified by the standard?

Comment: @Douglaso.moen I have a number of reasons to disagree with you.  First, [live code](http://ideone.com/ON7MWS).  Second, the current draft standard 21.4/5 Class template
basic_string [basic.string] explicitly mentions a `size_type`, and `std::string` **is** `std::basic_string<char>`.  There is such a thing as `std::string::size_type`, and it happens to be `std::size_t`.  If I am mistaken, can you please provide a citation?

Answer (score 3):

It does not know what string you are referring to, `npos` is just a static const member that represents the maximum value representable and in this case represents and eror, if we look at what cppreference says about [std::basic_string::npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

> This is a special value equal to the maximum value representable by the type size_type. The exact meaning depends on context, but it is generally used either as end of string indicator by the functions that expect a string index or as the error indicator by the functions that return a string index.

which matches the definition for `npos` in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) in section `21.4` *Class template basic_string* paragraph *5*:

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

which is a bit odd since since *size_type* is *unsigned* but is due to the integral conversion rules in section `4.7` *Integral conversions* which says:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).[...]

guarantees that `-1` will be converted to the largest unsigned value. It may be easier to see using the wording from the draft C99 standard which says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.

which gives us `MAX + 1 -1` which is `MAX`.